# Multiple shell commands in python (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I'm working on a windows machine and I want to set a variable in the shell and want to use it with another shell command, like:

```
set variable = abc
echo %variable%
```

I know that I could do this using `os.system(com1 && com2)` but I also know, that this is considered 'bad style' and it should be possible by using the subprocess module, but I don't get how.
Here is what I got so far:

```
proc = Popen('set variable=abc', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
proc.communicate(input=b'echo %variable%)
```

But neither line seems to work, both commands don't get executed. Also, if I type in nonexisting commands, I don't get an error. How is the proper way to do it?

Comment: The shell started by `Popen` isn't waiting on its standard input; the `set` command runs and then the shell exits without trying to read anything from standard input. Your command in this case (from the Python script's perspective) is a single shell script that happens to consist of two shell commands, not a pair of shell commands.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest making this more explicitly about Windows in the title and tagging. You'd get a *very* different answer on UNIX.

Comment: ...in general, though, the thing you're relying on (shell variables being set and expanded) relies on *having a shell*, so in the UNIX world, best practice would be to rework what you're doing entirely, to where it doesn't depend on shell variables at all.

Answer (score 1):

`Popen` can only execute one command or shell script. You can simply provide the whole shell script as single argument using `;` to separate the different commands:

```
proc = Popen('set variable=abc;echo %variable%', shell=True)
```

Or you can actually just use a multiline string:

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call('''echo 1
... echo 2
... ''', shell=True)
1
2
0
```

<sup>The final `0` is the return-code of the process</sup>

The `communicate` method is used to write to the stdin of the process. In your case the process immediately ends after running `set variable` and so the call to `communicate` doesn't really do anything.

You could spawn a shell and then use `communicate` to write the commands:

```
>>> proc = Popen(['sh'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>>> proc.communicate('echo 1; echo 2\n')
('1\n2\n', '')
```

Note that `communicate` also closes the streams when it is done, so you cannot call it mulitple times. If you want an interactive session you hvae to write directly to `proc.stdin` and read from `proc.stdout`.

---

By the way: you can specify an `env` parameter to `Popen` so *depending on the circumstances* you may want to do this instead:

```
proc = Popen(['echo', '%variable%'], env={'variable': 'abc'})
```

Obviously this is going to use the `echo` executable and not shell built-in but it avoids using `shell=True`.

Comment: This doesn't work (for me). If I type: 
    proc = Popen('echo abc;echo 123', shell=True)
    output=proc.communicate()[0]
    print(output)
I get `abc;echo123`, so it doesn't read it as 2 lines/commands

Comment: @AracKnight `>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call('echo 1; echo 2', shell=True)
1
2
` It works for me. You should specify exactly what code you are using in your question. Also, are you on Windows or linux? The `;` works on linux, I'm not sure whether powershell/batch files use a different separator. But then: you can also use a multiline string as a command `call('echo 1\necho 2', shell=True)`.

Comment: Im working on Windows 10 64bit. I'm setting a password for a Database connection in the first line as an environment variable so I can call psql in the next line and connect to the database. With using `call('echo abc\necho 123', shell=True)` I get `abc` as output, so the second command is still not working.

Comment: @AracKnight If that is your use case I believe you should do what I describe in the end: provide the env variable by the `env` parameter instead of hacking using the shell.

Comment: When I specify an `env` parameter to Popen I can't call psql anymore without knowing the exact path of the `psql.exe`, since I usually run it from the PATH Variable, wich gets ignored by Popen if its passed an `env`. Also however I might be able to work around my current problem, I'd really like to know how such purposes are achieved in general, since I might run into similar problems in the future.

Comment: @AracKnight You can just do this to preserve your process environment: `import os; new_env = os.environ.copy(); new_env['variable'] = 123` then pass `env=new_env`.